# Use repetition to name objects in Java

Tags: java, variables, object, repeat

How can I use repetition to name objects in Java? I want to create 52 objects (cards) like this

```
Card1
Card2
...
Card52
```

and I'm thinking something like this

```
int i=1;

while (i<=52){
  Card Card<i> = new Card();
  i=i+1;
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You need to read an introductory book on Java programming, from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your objects in a list instead:

```
List<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>();

while (i<=52){
  Card card = new Card();
  list.add(card);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: @TheEwook why to use list if he know the size. List is slower in performance then array because it is dynamic.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Nice catch, ha. This will also create 53 cards, if `i` starts at 0. Even better would be to use a for loop instead of a while. Much more idiomatic. `for (int i=0; i < 52; ++i)`

Comment: @Nikhil Lists are also more type-safe (covariance etc), and an `ArrayList` delegates pretty directly to an array.

Comment: @yshavit In the original question `int i = 1;`, but yes that's better.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline True, I missed that due to the formatting. Well, indexing by 1 in Java is a sure way to confuse people who skim the code!

Comment: I will use ArrayList because it fits better in the program (create a Deck of cards and taking away cards), thanks for your rapid comments!

Answer (score 7):

You should better use arrays

```
Card[] cards = new Card[52];
for(int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
    cards[i] = new Card();
```

After that you may use for example

```
card[14]
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use arrays for something like this using their index in a similar manner to your numbering scheme.

```
Card[] deck = new Card[52];

for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
    deck[i] = new Card();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider making a Card class and using enums for suit and card number. This might make it a little simpler to manage. For example, you could try something like the following:

```
enum SUIT{
    CLUB,
    SPADE,
    DIAMOND,
    HEART
}

enum CARD_NUM{
    ACE,
    TWO,
    ...
    KING
}

public class Card{
    private final SUIT suit;
    private final CARD_NUM cardNum;

    public Card(SUIT suit, CARD_NUM cardNum){
        this.suit=suit;
        this.cardNum=cardNum;
    }
    ...
}
```